# How to solve this definite integral? (Substitution method didn't help)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> $$\int_{1}^{1+2\pi}\cos(x)e^{(-\sin^2(x))}dx$$

an intuitive substitution would be $t = \sin(x)$ so we get $dt = \cos(x)dx$ and we're done with the $\cos(x)$, and then the range of integration would be from $\sin(1)$ to $\sin(1)$ which means we get $0$ as answer. But that doesn't satisfy the substitution method rules, because $t = \sin(x)\to x = \arcsin(t)$ and the output of this function is in the range $[\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]\nsubseteq [1,1+2\pi]$, so we're out of range. 
I'm really wondering how to correctly solve this integral, any help or push in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try graphing the integrand.

Comment: @B.Goddard Thanks for the help I've noticed that the integrand is an even function, but I'm not sure how to keep going, what I tried to do is to reach something like $I = A -BI$ where $I$ is my integral and $A,B\in \mathbb{R}, B \neq -1,0$ so I could do $I = (A/B)$, but still didn't reach anything close and always complicating stuff.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is your integrand, you should be able to prove that $f(\pi-x) = -f(x)$.  Then break up your integral into pieces that add up to $0.$

Comment: I think you need to review the rules for integration by substitution, because you've underestimated their scope. Hint: $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\operatorname{erf}\sin x=e^{-\sin^2x}\cos x$ integrates to $0$ on any period of $\sin x$, regardless of the concerns you raise.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the information, I think I didn't write the title clearly, I know that there's other substitutions that may work, not sure if that's what you implied, but I don't clearly understand the function you wrote

Comment: Understandable, but never mind [the specific example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function): $\frac{d}{dx}f(\sin x)=f'(\sin x)\cos x$ will integrate to $0$ on any period of $\sin x$ provided $f$ is bounded, continuous, well-defined etc. on $[-1,\,1]$, the range of $\sin x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand the integral as

$$\int_1^{1+2\pi} \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx = \left\{\int_0^{2\pi} - \int_0^1 + \int_{2\pi}^{1+2\pi} \right\} \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx$$

For the first integral, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx &= \left\{\int_0^\pi + \int_\pi^{2\pi}\right\} \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^\pi \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx - \int_0^\pi \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx \\[1ex]
&=0
\end{align*}$$

where the integral over $[\pi,2\pi]$ is done by substituting $x\mapsto x+\pi$. In other words, let $x = y + \pi$, so $dx=dy$ and $x\in[\pi,2\pi]\implies y\in[0,\pi]$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\int_\pi^{2\pi} \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx &= \int_0^\pi \cos(y + \pi) e^{-\sin^2(y+\pi)} \, dy & x \mapsto y+\pi \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^\pi -\cos(y) e^{-(-\sin(y))^2} \, dy & {\cos(y+\pi)=-\cos(y),\\\sin(y+\pi) = -\sin(y)}\\[1ex]
&= - \int_0^\pi \cos(x) e^{-\sin^2(x)} \, dx & y\mapsto x
\end{align*}$$

The integral over $[2\pi,1+2\pi]$ is equivalent to the integral over $[0,1]$ (easily shown by substituting $x\mapsto x-2\pi$), so the overall result is $0$.

Comment: An integral over a period doesn’t imply it is equal to zero. You must also be certain the positive and negative parts cancel out, which is true in this case but not in all cases

Comment: You're right, I skipped that detail. I should have just said it's easy to show the first integral is zero. edited

Comment: Hey there I know this is one month late, I've came to this question for a redo, but I got stuck in understanding how to show that $\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\cos(x)e^{-\sin^2(x)} = -\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)e^{-\sin^2(x)}$, using the substitution you suggested gets me to $\int^0_{-\pi}\cos(x)e^{-\sin^2(x)}$, I've tried substituting $2\pi - x$ to reach $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)e^{-\sin^2(x)}$, but still can't get them to cancel out like you did. (I know that the value of $\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)e^{-\sin^2(x)}$ is $0$, but I knew that by looking at the graph, I feel like im missing some important understanding).

Comment: @Pwaol I've added some more details. The substitution I originally suggested had a mistake in it, which I've also fixed. It occurred to me that explicitly changing variables might make things a bit clearer.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you, the part I was missing is using $\cos(x+\pi) = -\cos(x)$ and same for $\sin(x)$. Thanks alot for your help I've learnt alot of your answer!

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to note the function is odd about $x=1+{\pi}$. Hence the integral(which is essential signed area) , is odd